# How to make symbols from external vector graphics for use in a TikZ node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a piece of code that produces text boxes, and I have a .pdf vector graphic which I would like to add with an anchor definition and use wherever I'd like with a command like `\myvectorimage`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm,
    box/.style = {inner sep=0pt},
    lbl/.style = {draw, line width=2pt, rounded corners=10pt, inner sep=3mm, text width=44mm}
                      ]
    \node (first) at (5,5) [lbl]  {This text box is pointing somewhere};
    \node[anchor=south] at (first.north west) {\myvectorimage}
%above is only to show how i'm intending to use my graphics.

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the graphic I would like to use:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWz5l.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHlwo.jpg

Here is more or less what I want it to look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHlwo.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Here, I corrected syntax errors (missing `]`, missing `;`, stray blank line), and just use an `\includegraphics` to include the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\myvectorimage{\includegraphics{xNiad3b}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm,
    box/.style = {inner sep=0pt},
    lbl/.style = {draw, line width=2pt, rounded corners=10pt, inner sep=3mm, text width=44mm}]                      ]
    \node (first) at (5,5) [lbl]  {This text box is pointing somewhere};
    \node[anchor=south] at (first.north west) {\myvectorimage};
%above is only to show how i'm intending to use my graphics.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]